# multitables by conditions based on dataframe with jinja2

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, jinja2

I have this dataframe.

|  | name | date | income_eur | expenses_eur | total_eur | income_usd | expenses_usd | total_usd | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | investor 1 | 7/17/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 75 | 5 | 70 | good |
| 4 | investor 1 | 7/13/2022 | 21 | 30 | -9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | bad |
| 6 | investor 1 | 2/14/2022 | 25 | 66 | -41 | 0 | 0 | 0 | bad |
| 8 | investor 2 | 9/27/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 93 | 77 | 16 | good |
| 9 | investor 2 | 7/15/2022 | 56 | 60 | -4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | bad |
| 1 | investor 3 | 9/17/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 59 | -39 | bad |
| 2 | investor 3 | 6/13/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 54 | 6 | 48 | good |
| 3 | investor 3 | 1/7/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 88 | 79 | 9 | good |
| 5 | investor 3 | 7/11/2022 | 8 | 24 | -16 | 0 | 0 | 0 | bad |
| 7 | investor 3 | 7/17/2022 | 49 | 40 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | good |

I am using an excel that has many investors that is converted to a dataframe. Then, I generate an html with jinja2 and convert it to pdf with weasyprint.
There are only two currencies in my dataframe and for that reason I only need to have two tables with the correct column names for that currency.

Is there any way to have this result(look at the picture) with jinja2 for each of the investors. I mean two tables for each investor(two currencies). I really need help.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Hi, you should delete your previous post, since it is a duplicate now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186799/generating-multiple-tables-by-conditions-based-on-dataframe-with-jinja2

Answer (score 1):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            "investor 1",
            "investor 1",
            "investor 1",
            "investor 2",
            "investor 2",
            "investor 3",
            "investor 3",
            "investor 3",
            "investor 3",
            "investor 3",
        ],
        "date": [
            "7/17/2022",
            "7/13/2022",
            "2/14/2022",
            "9/27/2022",
            "7/15/2022",
            "9/17/2022",
            "6/13/2022",
            "1/7/2022",
            "7/11/2022",
            "7/17/2022",
        ],
        "income_eur": [0, 21, 25, 0, 56, 0, 0, 0, 8, 49],
        "expenses_eur": [0, 30, 66, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 24, 40],
        "total_eur": [0, -9, -41, 0, -4, 0, 0, 0, -16, 9],
        "income_usd": [75, 0, 0, 93, 0, 20, 54, 88, 0, 0],
        "expenses_usd": [5, 0, 0, 77, 0, 59, 6, 79, 0, 0],
        "total_usd": [70, 0, 0, 16, 0, -39, 48, 9, 0, 0],
        "condition": [
            "good",
            "bad",
            "bad",
            "good",
            "bad",
            "bad",
            "good",
            "good",
            "bad",
            "good",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Container for the different sub dataframes
dfs = []

for inv in df["name"].unique():
    for cur in ["eur", "usd"]:
        # Remove zeros rows
        temp = df.loc[
            df[[f"income_{cur}", f"expenses_{cur}", f"total_{cur}"]].any(axis=1), :
        ]

        # Extract sub dataframe
        temp = temp.loc[
            temp["name"] == inv,
            ["name", "date", f"income_{cur}", f"expenses_{cur}", f"total_{cur}"],
        ].reset_index(drop=True)

        # Add sum row
        temp.loc[temp.shape[0]] = ["" for _ in range(temp.shape[1])]
        temp.loc[temp.shape[0] - 1, f"total_{cur}"] = temp.loc[
            0: temp.shape[0] - 2, f"total_{cur}"
        ].sum()

        dfs.append(temp)
```

And then, for instance:

```py
print(dfs[4])
# Output
         name       date income_eur expenses_eur total_eur
0  investor 3  7/11/2022          8           24       -16
1  investor 3  7/17/2022         49           40         9
2                                                       -7

print(dfs[5])
# Output
         name       date income_usd expenses_usd total_usd
0  investor 3  9/17/2022         20           59       -39
1  investor 3  6/13/2022         54            6        48
2  investor 3   1/7/2022         88           79         9
3                                                       18
```

And to get the html if needed (not sure how you want to handle things in Jinja):

```py
print(dfs[4].to_html(index_names=False))
# Output
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>income_eur</th>
      <th>expenses_eur</th>
      <th>total_eur</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>investor 3</td>
      <td>7/11/2022</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>-16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>investor 3</td>
      <td>7/17/2022</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>-7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```